# Android start a map activity button crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-button, android-maps-v2

I am currently working on an android application that tracks a certain device and in one of the buttons (namely button2) is responsible for starting the MapsActivity. I copied the MapsActivity in another application in which it is the only activity and it worked fine however inside the other application when i try to access it using a button (button2) it crashes.

the MainActivity java code snippet (all needed imports are implemented):

```
package com.example.finalprototype;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
 Button button1;
 Button button3;
 Button button2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new LoadTracker().execute();

        }
    });
    button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });




    button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2Activity.class));
            finish();

        }
    });
}
```

The MapsActivity Code (all needed imports are implemented):

```
        package com.example.finalprototype;


 public class MapsActivity extends ActionBarActivity
  implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener,  OnMarkerClickListener{

final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
private GoogleMap myMap;
static final int POLYGON_POINTS=4;
ArrayList<LatLng> markers = new ArrayList<>();

Location myLocation;
TextView tvLocInfo;

boolean markerClicked;
PolygonOptions polygonOptions;
Polygon polygon;
Button setgeo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    setgeo =(Button)findViewById(R.id.setgeo);

    setgeo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            String Point1 = markers.get(0).toString();
            String Point2 = markers.get(2).toString();

        }
    });





    tvLocInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locinfo);

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();

    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    myMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    markerClicked = false;
}






@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
    }

}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    tvLocInfo.setText(point.toString());
    myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));

    markerClicked = false;
}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
    tvLocInfo.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());
    myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(point.toString()));
    markers.add(point);

    markerClicked = false;
}


@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    if(markerClicked){

        if(polygon != null){
            polygon.remove();
            polygon = null;
        }


        polygonOptions.add(marker.getPosition());
        polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLUE);
        polygonOptions.fillColor(0x3300FF);
        polygonOptions.strokeWidth(3);
        polygon = myMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);



    }else{
        if(polygon != null){
            polygon.remove();
            polygon = null;
        }

        polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions().add(marker.getPosition());
        markerClicked = true;
    }

    return true;
}


}
```

The activity_main xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context="com.app.layout.ZeroActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="GPS"
    style="@style/btnStyleAcapulco"
     />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Child Tracking System"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="E-Locator"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:text="GPS :"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="@style/btnStyleAcapulco"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:text="Track Your Child"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="@style/btnStyleAcapulco"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set GeoFence"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="@style/btnStyleAcapulco"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set Speed Limit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

The activity_maps xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MapsActivity"
android:weightSum="1">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="379dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_weight="0.92" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/locinfo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set GeoFence"
    android:id="@+id/setgeo"
    style="@style/btnStyleAcapulco"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Android Manifest:

`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCmRNOGr-q6m0p-Qq3QlVmrHkgEr8F39go" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: We need the logcat and stacktrace to pinpoint the crash.

Comment: Looks like some string is missing in your strings.xml file. Have you checked your strings.xml file for all the @string/xxxx  values in your manifest file? Especially for the @string/google_maps_key

Comment: Maybe `title_activity_main_activity2` is missing in the strings.xml. That would make sense, since it is crashing when you are starting that activity.

Comment: @Ugur unfortunately everything seems to be in place in the strings.xml file however i am new to android so there is a good chance that i am missing something, so i will post the string.xml

Comment: Of course.....the problem was in the  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>  duplication in the manifest along with the placement of the tags, they should be right before the </application>  tag.